# Capistrano plugin to prevent deploy if one is running

Tags: ruby, capistrano

My team is in the process of using more and more capistrano.
We fighting a lot for our different environement (staging and production) and we are looking for a way to prevent someone to deploy with capistrano is a deploy is already running (with happened to us as couple of days ago).

Is there a plugin for such feature in capistrano v2 or should I elaborate something based on a lock/flag file ?

Answer (score 1):

Capistrano has variety of hooks that you can use to inject your code at definite phase of execution path of capistrano recipe. I am assuming that you want to prevent another deployments on SAME machine when the first is already running. If they are on different machine, I hope you should be having any problem!

A simple approach would a lock/flag file as you mentioned:

You can define the before and after hooks as below:

```
before "deploy:update_code", "any_namespace:acquire_lock" 
after "deploy:create_symlink", "any_namespace:release_lock"
```

and you should have the both tasks defined in your deploy.rb itself:

```
namespace :any_namespace do
 desc "attempts to acquire lock if available or exits"
 task :acquire_lock do
   present = capture("test -f /path/to/some/fixed/dir/deploy_lock  &&  echo \"yes\" || echo \"no\" ")
   if present == "yes"
       #means someone is already deploying on the same machine
       puts "someone is already deploying on the same machine."
       exit
   else
       #its safe to deploy, lets acquire the lock
       run 'touch /path/to/some/fixed/dir/deploy_lock'
       puts "Lock acquired successfully"
   end

 end

 desc "releases the acquire lock so others can deploy"
 task :release_lock do
   run("rm /path/to/some/fixed/dir/deploy_lock")
   puts "Released Lock successfully"
 end
end
```

NOTE that there are various hook available in capistrano which might be tighter and more useful. eg: started and finished hooks. I am not sure if they work perfectly but you can check them out and use an appropriate hook as you want.

Hope it helps :)